# Question about instance creation by using Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, initialization, factory-pattern

Here goes a command object which needs to be populated from a Spring form

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private Integer age;    

    /**
      * on-demand initialized
      */
    private Address address;

    // getter's and setter's

}
```

And Address

```
public class Address {

    private String street;

    // getter's and setter's

}
```

Now suppose the following MultiActionController

```
@Component
public class PersonController extends MultiActionController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("personRepository")
    private Repository<Person, Integer> personRepository;

    /**
      * mapped To /person/add
      */
    public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Person person) throws Exception {
        personRepository.add(person);

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/home.htm");
    }

}
```

Because Address attribute of Person needs to be initialized on-demand, i need to override *newCommandObject* to create an instance of Person to initiaze address property. Otherwise, i will get *NullPointerException*

```
@Component
public class PersonController extends MultiActionController {

    /**
      * code as shown above
      */

    @Override
    public Object newCommandObject(Class clazz) thorws Exception {
        if(clazz.isAssignableFrom(Person.class)) {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setAddress(new Address());

            return person;
        }
    }

}
```

Ok, Expert Spring MVC and Web Flow says

> Options for alternate object creation include pulling an instance from a BeanFactory or using method injection to transparently return a new instance.

First option

- pulling an instance from a BeanFactory

can be written as

```
@Override
public Object newCommandObject(Class clazz) thorws Exception {
    /**
      * Will retrieve a prototype instance from ApplicationContext whose name matchs its clazz.getSimpleName()
      */
    getApplicationContext().getBean(clazz.getSimpleName());
}
```

But what does he want to say by *using method injection to **transparently** return a new instance* ??? Can you show how i implement what he said ???

**ATT**: I know this funcionality can be filled by a SimpleFormController instead of MultiActionController. But **it is shown just as an example**, nothing else

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `MultiActionController`? It's deprecated in Spring 3, you really should be using `@Controller` instead, it's an awful lot easier.

Comment: @skaffman Sorry, i do not use Spring 3.0 (And i know it is deprecated in Spring 3.0) and i can get THE SAME convention over configuration without no Spring 3.0 MVC annotation. Thank you!

Comment: You can use `@Controller` in Spring 2.5 also, you don't need 3.0. The command-object binding is much simpler to understand. And your code is already littered with Spring MVC annotations, I don't understand you're reluctance to use `@Controller`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure he means using the `lookup-method` system as documented in [chapter 3 of the spring reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-method-injection)

Only down side is that `<lookup-method>` requires a no arg method rather than the `newCommandObject(Class)` method of `MultiActionController`.

this can be solved with something like:

```
public abstract class PersonController extends MultiActionController {

    /**
      * code as shown above
      */

    @Override
    public Object newCommandObject(Class clazz) thorws Exception {
        if(clazz.isAssignableFrom(Person.class)) {
            return newPerson();
        }
    }                          

    public abstract Person newPerson();
}
```

in the context file:

```
<bean id="personController" class="org.yourapp.PersonController">
  <lookup-method name="newPerson" bean="personPrototype"/>
</bean>
```

The down side is that using this sort of thing is you are kinda stuck with configuring the controller bean via xml it's not possible (certainly in < 3) to do this with annotations.

Comment: Thank you. I think you are right. No way to get the same behavior by using Spring annotations ???